# What is an Objective-C delegate?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, delegates

What is an Objective-C delegate?
For clarity, can you explain it with a good and precise example so that I can understand it?

Answer (score 2):

A delegate in Objective-C is essentially a pointer to an object that another class uses to notify it of events.

For example, class A asks you for a delegate. You tell it [this] instance of class B will do.

```
[a setDelegate:b];
```

Then in class A's methods and actions, it will invoke pre-defined methods on your delegate object like so:

```
-(void)actionFinished:(id)sender
{
    [delegate a:self finishedWithResult:RESULT_OK];
}
```

So your delegate object should be implemented to respond to that message:

```
-(void)a:(A *)a finishedWithResult:(int)result { /* respond */ }
```