# Objective-C Delegate question

Tags: objective-c

**From reference: [Can someone explain what a delegate is with an example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408774/objective-c-delegate-explanation-with-example)**

NICK wrote:

> For example, class A asks you for a
>   delegate. You tell it [this] instance
>   of class B will do.
>
> [a setDelegate:b];

What is *a*?  Is it a instance of Class of A?

Comment: You should have added this as a comment on Nick's answer, on the original page.

Answer (score 1):

Sending messages to objects using Objective-C is done using the square brackets.

You have instance methods, they are denoted with a - (minus) sign ahead of the return type of the method, like so:

```
- (void)setDelegate:(id <SomeDelegateProtocol>)delegate;
```

Alternatively you have the class methods denoted with a + (plus) sign:

```
+ (NSArray *)arrayWithObject:(id)object;
```

The first text within the brackets stands for the receiver of that message, in case of an instance message this will be an object pointer. Otherwise, when you deal with a class message, you use the class it's name.

So *a* is indeed a pointer for an instance, probably of class A (well, it actually is just the name of the variable the object is assigned to. It can be of any class).

Answer (score 0):

This example is presuming that we have two classes, class A and class B, and that we have one instance of each of them; `a` is an instance of A, and `b` is an instance of B:

```
ClassA *a = [[[ClassA alloc] init] autorelease];
ClassB *b = [[[ClassB alloc] init] autorelease];
```

We're also presuming that class A has some kind of delegate variable, and a method `setDelegate:` that changes the value of that variable. In general, a delegate is an instance of an object that receives messages about another object's activities or defines its behavior in some way. So, for example, if class A has some method `doFoo`, class B might have a *delegate* method `a:didFoo:` that gets called from class A whenever it does Foo.

But before the delegate can fulfill its purpose, the object it's to receive messages about has to know that it has a delegate. So we have to set our instance of class B as class A's delegate by using class A's `setDelegate:` method:

```
[a setDelegate:b];
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is:

Yes.

Hope that clears things up.
For longer answers see Tim & JoostK.

If you're not familiar with Obj-C's message passing syntax you should probably get more practice with that before worrying about delegates. Once you understand message passing, delegates are straightforward.