# Do we have notification for image capture event in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, camera

I want to get the timestamp when the image is captured in my application. Do we have any notification when the camera is clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [UIImagePickerController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) delegate:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    NSDictionary *metadataDictionary = (NSDictionary *)[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata];
        // do something with the metadata

    NSLog(@"meta : %@ \n\n",metadataDictionary);
}
```

Comment: yes exactly , this is the delegate method which gets called after that you have captured image or chosen a picture from library

Comment: @NeverBe: Thanks, But i can't understand how this method get called?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html

Comment: @pushpa : Its a delegate.. You can refer this link for knowing more about the delegates.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534094/what-is-a-delegate-in-objective-cs-iphone-development

Comment: @ NeverBe and Aravindhanarvi: Thanks, Using this method we can capture the image from our class. But how to capture the timestamp when the image is captured, how to observe from my application?