# Why don't work scrollView methods in my app?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

In one of my view controller (using Storyboard and ARC mode), i add two scrollView methods?

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
{
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
}
```

Both of them are not work on my app.

I already add scroll view as sub view of self.view
But, why these scroll view methods are not work? 
Please, give me some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are UIScrollViewDelegate methods.You have to properly setup the VC as the scrollview delegate and connect the delegate from xib to the VC

1. Add `<UIScrollViewDelegate>` to your VC

**.h File**

`@interface ExampleVC <UIScrollViewDelegate>`

makes the exampleVC a reciever for the UIScrollViewDelegate methods.

1. From Xib connect the scrollview delegates to the files owner (Right
   click on the scrollview in storyboard and there drag the delegate to
   the view controller object and thats it)

**EDIT**
 If you are creating a scrollview programatically

> [scrollView setDelegate:self];

can do the job

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I'm sorry for my incomplete question. I don't use delegate. I just use view controllers in storyboard and connect them with segue. So, how can i do? Please.

Comment: the remaining to do is what i said

Comment: you have to include these steps to the code and then you can see the methods hitting

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534094/what-is-a-delegate-in-objective-cs-iphone-development

Comment: i add interface ExampleVC <UIScrollViewDelegate> is ok in .h file. But, i create scrollView from program(in .m file). Not from IB. How can i do in .m file? I'm new in iOS. Please, give me a patient. :)

Comment: @NightHunter  : From Xib connect the scrollview delegates to the files owner (Right click on the scrollview in storyboard and there drag the delegate to the view controller object and thats it)

Comment: @ Lithu T.V, sorry for my late reply, i really thanks you for your help. Now, i can scroll my app. Thanks you so much.