# iOS Segue And Passing Data Back

Tags: ios, arrays, storyboard, segue

I'm passing an array along 3 view controllers which is working fine. When it gets to the last screen it processes the complete array as i want.

However I'm having an issue in that whenever the back button is pressed the latest array data gets lost. I'm inserting data using a specific index.

How do i ensure the data does not get lost i.e. do i have to pass back the updated array to the previous view controllers?

Also, fyi, I'm using ios7 with starboards.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you have to pass the array back.

Comment: The second answer here solved my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19343519/pass-data-back-to-previous-viewcontroller