# Why this struct with optional values returns nothing?

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

I visited [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24065442/why-do-i-need-to-declare-an-optional-value-as-nil-explicitly-in-struct-swift) to know about optionals and I saw a quote from the docs, which I quote again.

> If your custom type has a stored property that is logically allowed to have “no value”—perhaps because its value cannot be set during initialization, or because it is allowed to have “no value” at some later point—declare the property with an optional type. Properties of optional type are automatically initialized with a value of nil, indicating that the property is deliberately intended to have “no value yet” during initialization.

So I have the same condition. I have some variables that *may* have some values or not. So here's my struct

```swift
struct Notification {
    var type : String?
    var dp : String?
    var name : String?
    var postImage : String?
    var whomenc : String?
}
```

So I'm trying to create a struct array but **whenever the struct is initialized, I get nothing in return**

```swift
obj.forEach {
    guard let type = $0["type"] as? String else {return}
    print("type = \(type)")
    guard let dp = $0["dp"] as? String else {return}
    print("dp = \(dp)")
    guard let name = $0["name"] as? String else {return}
    print("name = \(name)")
    guard let postimg = $0["postimg"] as? String else {return}
    print("postimg = \(postimg)")
    guard let whomenc:String = $0["whomenc"] as? String else {return}
    print("whomenc = \(whomenc)")
    let notification = Notification(type: type, dp: dp, name: name, postImage: postimg, whomenc: whomenc)
    self.notifiArray.append(notification)
    print("notifiArray.count = \(self.notifiArray.count)") // this satement doesn't gets executed.
}
```

And this is what I get in the log

```
type = commentCommented
dp = default.jpg
name = testt
postimg = 69663rocketleague32bitdx914102018180636.mp4
type = commentCommented
dp = default.jpg
name = testt
postimg = 69663rocketleague32bitdx914102018180636.mp4
type = followed
dp = default.jpg
name = bott1
type = followed
dp = default.jpg
name = bott2
```

I tried printing the notification variable and it is empty. I tried printing the notifiArray which returns as `[]`

The array is declared as

```swift
var notifiArray = [Notification]()
```

Any idea why this behavior?

Comment: You could *really* clean this code up a lot by extracting that `Notification ` initialization logic into a ... `Notification` initializer. And you should use `map` instead of `forEach` + `append`.

Comment: @Alexander I didn't understand. Also, I don't want to return anything, Why should I use .map?

Comment: 1) You can make a new initializer on your `Notification` type that takes a dictionary, and encapsulates all this logic of initializing a `Notification` from a dictionary. 2) You're trying to take the elements of one array (`obj`), transform them in some way (use the elements to initialize new `Notification` instances), and then product a new array of results. There is a name for that operation, and it's `map`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement is not succeeding:

```
guard let whomenc:String = $0["whomenc"] as? String else {return}
```

either because the key `"whomenc"` doesn't exist or the type isn't a `String`.  The `guard` statement then `return`s from the closure and does nothing more for that dictionary.

Since you can create a `Notification` even if some values are `nil`, you could remove the `guard` statements and pass the (possibly `nil`) values to the `Notification` initializer:

```
obj.forEach {
    let type = $0["type"] as? String
    print("type = \(type ?? "nil")")
    let dp = $0["dp"] as? String
    print("dp = \(dp ?? "nil")")
    let name = $0["name"] as? String
    print("name = \(name ?? "nil")")
    let postimg = $0["postimg"] as? String
    print("postimg = \(postimg ?? "nil")")
    let whomenc = $0["whomenc"] as? String
    print("whomenc = \(whomenc ?? "nil")")
    let notification = Notification(type: type, dp: dp, name: name, postImage: postimg, whomenc: whomenc)
    self.notifiArray.append(notification)
    print("notifiArray.count = \(self.notifiArray.count)") // this satement doesn't gets executed.
}
```

Comment: Well, why don't I have any error or warning in the console about this? Or I shouldn't expect one because I'm using a guard statement?

Comment: There is no error or warning here as far as Swift is concerned.  It is just executing your code.  You said with the `guard` statement, if there's no value in the dictionary or it isn't a `String` then `return` from the closure and do nothing more for this element.

Comment: @weegee Swift has definite initialization analysis, a compiler step that verifies that all variables of a struct/class are initialized before the completion of the initializer. That would have caught this error. But by making all of your fields optional, and by not using your own initializer to set the variables, you've voluntarily waived your access to Swift's definite initialization guarantees.