# Passing int back in NavigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, nsinteger

I'm sitting with a issue which I can't solve in a while. I must be doing something very wrong.
I have 2 views, a `UIView` and `UITableView`. They're embedded with a `NavigationController`.

In the second view; `TableView`, I want to pass a `NSInteger` back to the UIView, the first view.

I've used the solution of https://stackoverflow.com/a/19343715/3355194 but didn't work for me. It gives me a 0 value back in the UIView. In the TableView it does give me right value of `numberOnSectionInTableView`.
Also tried some other solution but same result.

What I did so far.

In the `TableView.h`:

```
@protocol senddataProtocol <NSObject>

-(void)sendBadgeIntBack:(int*)section;

@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;
```

`TableView.m`:

```
@synthesize delegate;

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    self.section = [self.tableView numberOfSections];
    section = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications] count];

    NSLog(@"Number of sections: %i", section-1);

    return (int)[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications] count]/2;
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [delegate sendBadgeIntBack:&(section)];
}
```

`UIView.h`:

```
 @property (nonatomic) int section;
```

`UIView.m`:
It gives me a 0 value here.

```
-(void)sendBadgeIntBack:(int*)section
{
    NSLog(@"The numbers of sections in tableView are: %i", self.section);
}
```

Hope you could help me find the solution.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using pass by reference `(int *)` instead of pass by value `(int)` which you should use for primitive values. To simplify, objects get a star, integers, floats, structs etc. don't.

Additionally, if the problem still persists, you probably didn't set your delegate properly, put a breakpoint in the method and check if it gets called properly.

Comment: Thanks mate, also for the tip, new to Obj-c. I knew it only was a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 2):

In the TableView.h:

```
@protocol senddataProtocol <NSObject>

-(void)sendBadgeIntBack:(int)section_selected;

@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;
 @property (nonatomic) int section;
```

TableView.m:

```
@synthesize delegate;

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    self.section = [self.tableView numberOfSections];
    section = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications] count];

    NSLog(@"Number of sections: %i", section-1);

    return (int)[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications] count]/2;
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [delegate sendBadgeIntBack:section];
}
```

UIView.h:

```
 @property (nonatomic) int section;
```

UIView.m: It gives me a 0 value here.

```
-(void)sendBadgeIntBack:(int*)section_selected;
{
self.section = section_selected;
    NSLog(@"The numbers of sections in tableView are: %i", self.section);
}
```