# How to Pass information Back in iOS when reversing a Gesture Recognizer using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, storyboard, uigesturerecognizer

I'm new to iOS Development, and Swift. And many of the resources I've found on the Google are written in Objective-C, which I am not familiar also.

I have two view Storyboards, S1 and S2. Each of them have at least 1 View Controller, VC1 and VC2 respectively. I go from S1 to S2 using a Gesture Recognizer, not a Segue. On S2, I select a data taken from a Table View. When I press a value from the list on the table, I would like to send that values back to S1.

What's the best way to do this using Swift? Thanks!

Comment: have you implemented gesture recognizer delegate method? If so, show the code.

Comment: Please have a look at this question: [Pass data back to previous viewcontroller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19343519/pass-data-back-to-previous-viewcontroller)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Answer (score 1):

You can use NSNotificationCenter for that

Add Oberver in S1

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "NotificationMethod:", name:"NotificationName", object: nil)

func NotificationMethod(notification: NSNotification){
    //Take Action on Notification
}
```

Call it from S2 tableview click and pass userInfo.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("NotificationName", object: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Custom protocol techniques.

**Write in S1**

```
@IBOutlet var textField: UITextField! 
@IBOutlet var datalbl: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true

}

func myMethod(text:String){
    datalbl.text = text
}

@IBAction func nextViewBtn(sender:UIButton){
    let nextObjvc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("S2") as! S2
    nextObjvc.delegate = self
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextObjvc, animated: true)
}
```

**Write in S2**

```
@IBOutlet var fullNameLabel: UILabel!
var str:String = String()
var myArray:NSArray = NSArray()
var delegate:myProtocol?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    myArray = ["APPLE","BLACKBERRY","CANON","DELEGAT","EMIT","FLAG","GENERAL"]

    self.fullNameLabel.text = str
}
```

Hope it may help full for you.

Answer (score 1):

The preferred way for this would be to use [delegation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html), e.g. tell `S2` to report back to `S1`.

Another answer tried to make this point already, yet didn't make clear what is going on.

The idea is to have `S2` hold a reference to `S1` and report back. It comes in handy that you are not using segues; they would make it minimally more complex.

### Protocol

You can do so by creating a [protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html) for communication:

```
protocol ReportBackProtocol {
  func reportValues(someValues : SomeType)
}
```

### `S1`

Within `S1`, you implement `ReportBackProtocol` like so:

```
class S1 : UIViewController, ReportBackProtocol {

// all your S1 class things


func reportValues(someValues : SomeType) {


   // do with the values whatever you like in the scope of S1
}
```

And assign your `S1` instance as a delegate of your `S2` instance where you create it, before you present it:

```
let s2 = S2()
s2.delegate = self
// present it as you already do
```

### `S2`

In `S2`, wherever you have compiled your values (let's call them `x`) and are ready to send them back:

```
self.delegate?.reportValues(x)
```

You also need to add the delegate instance variable to `S2` like so:

```
 weak var delegate : ReportBackProtocol?
```

This should do the trick; please let me know if you run into problems or do not understand parts of the concept.