# Pass object to another controller connecting through segue

Tags: ios, swift

hello I am new to programming. So I have some basic questions and then I need the solution of the problem which I am having.

I have created a Model Class

```
class Trip: NSObject {

    var tripTitle: String
    var tripSummary: String

   static var trips = [Trip]()

    init(tripTitle: String, tripSummary: String) {
        self.tripTitle = tripTitle
        self.tripSummary = tripSummary

    }

   class func addTrip(tripTitle: String, tripSummary: String){

            let t = Trip(tripTitle: tripTitle, tripSummary: tripSummary)

           trips.append(t)
        }

}
```

**TripsDetailController**

```
@IBAction func previewButtomPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        let tripTitle = tripTitleTxt.text!
        let tripSummary = tripSummaryTxt.text!



        Trip.addTrip(tripTitle, tripSummary: tripSummary)
       // let optionaltrip = Trip(tripTitle: tripTitle, tripSummary: tripSummary)


}



override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ShowTripPreviewTableViewController" {


        let tripPreviewTableViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! TripPreviewTableViewController
       // how can I pass the object here 
    }
}
```

how can I pass the object in segue

**tripPreviewTableViewController**

In this class I know I have to declare a variable here also but don't know what would be the datatype and also how can I access the value

and also I want to know what would be the best approach  from these two

```
 Trip.addTrip(tripTitle, tripSummary: tripSummary)
```

or

```
let trip = Trip(tripTitle: tripTitle, tripSummary: tripSummary)
```

should I have to create an array and assign values or go to the second method of creating an object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Pass information Back in iOS when reversing a Gesture Recognizer using Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34651357/how-to-pass-information-back-in-ios-when-reversing-a-gesture-recognizer-using-sw)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do you pass data between view controllers in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25215476/how-do-you-pass-data-between-view-controllers-in-swift)?

Answer (score 1):

Use the destinationViewController:

In the tripPreviewTableViewController you need to add new optional variable type of Trip:

```
var trip : Trip!
```

and now you can transfer your object with destinationViewController:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ShowTripPreviewTableViewController" {

        let tripPreviewTableViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! TripPreviewTableViewController
        tripPreviewTableViewController.trip = (Your Trip Object)

    }
}
```

//Update

First you need to declare your Trip object in TripsDetailController:

```
var tripToPass = Trip!
```

then orient it with one of these ways:

```
tripToPass = Trip(tripTitle:"title",tripSummary:"summary")
//or get the Trip out of your trips array:
tripToPass = Trip.trips[index]
```

after that you can pass the trip object:

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "ShowTripPreviewTableViewController" {

```
        let tripPreviewTableViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! TripPreviewTableViewController
        tripPreviewTableViewController.trip = tripToPass

    }
}
```

Comment: when I do this 
 tripPreviewTableViewController.trip = Trip 

It says Cannot assign value of type 'Trip.Type' to type 'Trip'

Comment: @hellosheikh **(Your Trip Object)** refers to the **instance** of `Trip` that you want to pass to your `TripPreviewTableViewController`