# How Do I Notify Parent View Controller When Popover Has Been Dismissed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I have a UIViewController that has a button which in turn launches another UIViewController in the form of a Popover.

Now on the popover view controller I can perform an action (Add User). How can I notify the parent view controller when dismissing the popover view controller that an action has been performed i.e user added?

Thanks

Comment: you can use notificationcenter..i mean use observer

Comment: use delegate pattern.

Comment: Use this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/19343715/6438500

Comment: Thanks guys, I have gone with the notification approach because it's quite a simple approach and in theory it just is a notification.

Comment: If you have two instance of the same view controller opening the popover (common in a tab-based app), when the notification fires, both instance will receive the notification and both instance will close the popover even though you might just want to close it in one of them. Delegate pattern is the recommended solution.

Comment: Indeed. I generally prefer to avoid Notifications unless it is about UI changes which do not have any other impact on App's functionality. Moreover, in case of a bug, Notifications make it difficult to debug the issue which is why I prefer delegate pattern