# Swift 3 Protocol and Delegate Method?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, delegates

I've Looked around SO, and read a good number of blogs to find out how to accomplish my goal. The most understandable post I came across was the one here  [Pass data back to previous viewcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19343519/pass-data-back-to-previous-viewcontroller/33229483#33229483). I'm sure my understanding is mixed up but what I am trying to accomplish is removing an annotation from the map when I swipe a cell in my second view.

Removing the annotation from the CoreData is not a problem, removing the pin when I click the rightCallOut is not an issue either. The problem comes when I want to remove the annotation from the map in VC1 from an action in VC2. Where am I misunderstanding this simple process and how do I accomplish it?

FirstViewController

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, PinRemoverDelegate {

    func removePin() {
        mapView.removeAnnotation(selectedAnnotation)
    }

}
```

SecondViewController

```
import UIKit

protocol PinRemoverDelegate: class {
   func removePin()
   }

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    weak var delegate: PinRemoverDelegate? = nil

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            let place = storedLocations[indexPath.row]
            context.delete(place)
            (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()

    // Attempt To remove The Pin
        delegate?.removePin()
        }

        tableView.reloadData()
    }

}
```

Comment: `SecondViewController` should have a `weak var delegate: PinRemoverDelegate?` property that is set to the view controller instance you want to send the message to.  Usually you'd assign the `delegate` in some code that owns or is aware of both view controllers.

Comment: Ill edit the post, I have implemented a weak var already, I just lost it in the quick copy/shorten code paste.

Comment: remember to set the delegate as self in your `FirstViewController`. Something like  `vc2.delegate = self`. it depends on how you present the `SecondViewController`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The misunderstanding is only how to remove the pin. Calling a removePin function is wrong. Simply reload the CoreData, since the pin has already been removed from the CoreData.