# Cannot Pass Data between TableViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, segue

Merry Christmas! I am currently making a "reminders" app at the moment. My "secondary" TableViews fail to pass data back into the "main" TableView. (please see image below). I need the data to pass back into the "main" TableView so that I can save it and display that into another TableView, so the user can see the tasks they have put in.

[image: My Storyboard, segue names in Red]

The code inside the IconTableViewController (and ShowTableViewController):

```
var userImage: String = ""
var userTitle: String = ""
var userDesc: String = ""
var frequency: String = ""

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if let navigationViewController = segue.destination as? UINavigationController {

        guard let viewController = navigationViewController.topViewController as? NewItemTableViewController else { return }

        let userImageNew = userImage
        let userTitleOld = userTitle
        let userDescOld = userDesc
        let frequencyOld = frequency

        viewController.selectedImage = userImageNew
        viewController.userTitle = userTitleOld
        viewController.userDesc = userDescOld
        viewController.selectedFrequency = frequencyOld
    }
}
```

The code inside NewItemTableViewController:

```
var selectedImage: String = ""
var selectedFrequency: String = ""
var userTitle: String = ""
var userDesc: String = ""

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showSelect" {
        let userImageOld = selectedImage
        let userTitleNew = titleTextField.text
        let userDescNew = descTextView.text
        let frequencyOld = selectedFrequency

        let viewController = segue.destination as! ShowTableViewController
        viewController.userImage = userImageOld
        viewController.userTitle = userTitleNew!
        viewController.userDesc = userDescNew!
        viewController.frequency = frequencyOld
    }

    if segue.identifier == "iconSelect" {
        let userImageOld = selectedImage
        let userTitleNew = titleTextField.text
        let userDescNew = descTextView.text
        let frequencyOld = selectedFrequency

        let viewController = segue.destination as! IconTableViewController
        viewController.userImage = userImageOld
        viewController.userTitle = userTitleNew!
        viewController.userDesc = userDescNew!
        viewController.frequency = frequencyOld
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like `NewItemTableViewController`is not yet top `viewController` on the navigation stack. Try accessing it in the same trivial way,

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if let viewController = segue.destination as? NewItemTableViewController {

        let userImageNew = userImage
        let userTitleOld = userTitle
        let userDescOld = userDesc
        let frequencyOld = frequency

        viewController.selectedImage = userImageNew
        viewController.userTitle = userTitleOld
        viewController.userDesc = userDescOld
        viewController.selectedFrequency = frequencyOld
    }
}
```

You should put a breakpoint inside above method `prepare(for segue` and see if it is being called. Because i feel you don't have `unwind segue` as these `viewControllers` are just pushed on the navigation stack. So in that case you can also use `viewWillDisappear` to set the data by accessing `NewItemTableViewController` from the navigation stack. Something as below,

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    if let vc = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.first(where: { $0 is NewItemTableViewController }) as? NewItemTableViewController {
        // Set data.
    }
}
```

Comment: You're correct, the prepare (for segue...) method doesn't get called at all. However, using the viewWillDisappear method, it gives me the following error: Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'selectedImage'

Comment: @Anthony Yes, i edited the answer. Please check, you need to cast it as `NewItemTableViewController` as above.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Delegate` to push data back to `NewItemTableViewController`. You can refer this thread: [Pass data back to previous viewcontrolle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19343519/pass-data-back-to-previous-viewcontroller)