# Pass variable to other view controller via back button

Tags: swift, variables, segue, viewcontroller

I have two view controllers. One is navigated to with a "show" segue. There is a back button in the UINavigationBar that I have not changed. The back button goes back to the initial view controller. In the view controller with the back button, I am storing data in a variable.

How can I pass this data to my initial view controller?

I have tried:

```
viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let vc = ViewController()
    vc.data = items
}
```

but the data in the initial view controller is empty when printed.

I've attempted to use:

```
prepare(for segue: ...)
```

but I'm not sure what segue the back button uses.

I can't seem to add an action of the back button to my view controller either.

Comment: `Let vc = ViewController()` That's creating a whole new object, not the one you think of.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass data back to previous viewcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19343519/pass-data-back-to-previous-viewcontroller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a delegate. First, create a protocol:

```
protocol getItemsDelegate {
    func getItems(_ items: [String])
}
```

In your first view controller's class definition add getItemsDelegate:

```
class myFirstViewController: UIViewController,getItemsDelegate
```

Add this to the prepare method in your first view controller:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let vc = segue.destination as! mySecondViewController
    vc.delegate = self
}
```

Lastly, in your first view controller, add this:

```
func getItems(_ items: [String]) {
    // Do something with items
}
```

In your second view controller, declare the following property:

```
var delegate: getItemsDelegate?
```

Then:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
   delegate?.getItems(items)
}
```

This is just another way to do it.

Comment: Using viewWillDisappear for passing data back is very common mistake. The problem is viewWillDisappear will be called every time user starts swipe back, and if user stops on half way you will stay on same viewController  but delegation method will be activated and it can cause bugs.

Comment: Never thought of that possibility of a user stopping a swipe.  However, in this case, I believe there is a Back button which wouldn't require a swipe.  But that potential bug is good to keep in mind!

Comment: In navigation controller swipe back is enabled by default, and as a part of good UX it is not recommended to disable it. So yes, it is very important to keep that potential bug in mind.

Answer (score 1):

`vc` isn't the same controller as controller which you're going back to.

---

Create closure variable in second controller with array of your models as parameter

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    var callback: (([Item]) -> Void)?
}
```

then in first controller's `prepare(for:sender:)` assign destination's `callback` and declare that you want to change first controller's `data` when `callback` is called

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "yourSegueIdentifier" {
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
        destinationVC.callback = { items in
            self.data = items
        }
    }
}
```

Then when you need to (means in second controller's `viewWillDisappear`) call `callback` with given items

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    callback?(items)
}
```

Comment: perhaps a `[weak self]` in the callback?

Comment: prepare() gives me an error.

Cannot call value of non-function type '(([Item]) -> Void)?'

Comment: @Nathaniel my mistake, check edit. I forgot for assign symbol