# How I can transfer data between controllers when returning to the last screen? Swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

In the application, I am asked to select a category, when I click, I move to the next screen from the tableView, and when I click on the desired category, it should be saved and return to the previous controller, where instead of "select a category" my chosen category will be.

I using by this method `navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)`, which brings me back to the last screen.
As I understand it, prepare is not called, but since I know exactly where I'm going, I can, in the method from which I call pop ..., get access to the controller I am switching to and pass it the necessary properties? But how?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  let currentCell = categories[indexPath.row]
    /?
    /?
  navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Using the `Delegate`-pattern

Comment: How? I don't quite understand?

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19343519/pass-data-back-to-previous-viewcontroller

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass data back to previous viewcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19343519/pass-data-back-to-previous-viewcontroller)

Comment: You can use closures to solve that. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56075711/5716829

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you go to the select screen do

```
let vc = ///
vc.delegate = self
// push
```

then inside `didASelectRowAt`

```
class CategoryViewController:UIViewController {
 weak var delegate:PreviousVC?
 ////
}

delegate?.sendData(someData)
navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

---

Another option inside  `didASelectRowAt` to

```
// access previous vc
let previousVC = self.navigationController!.viewControllers[self.navigationController!.viewControllers.count - 2] as! PreviousVc
previousVC.sendData(someData)
// pop here
```

---

**Edit:** inside the firstVC

```
     override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let secondVC = segue.destination as? SecondViewController {
          secondVC.delegate = self   
        }
    }
```

Comment: I can't do vc.delegate = self "Value of type 'CategoryViewController' has no member 'delegate'"

Comment: replace `PreviousVC` with your own name and see edit of `CategoryViewController`

Comment: Why then during the transition the data does not change ... 
let currentCell = categories[indexPath.row]
delegate?.defaultTransaction.category = currentCell
navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

Comment: verified delegate is not nil with `delegate!`

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: try `delegate!.defaultTransaction.category = currentCell `

Comment: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: do you assigned the delegate ? also do you have a segue ?

Comment: Yes. In prepare segue (firstVC) I created let vc/// vc.delegate = self
and in secondVC I created weak var delegate: FitstVC? 
and in method didSelectedRowAt trying to transfer the data

Comment: but when I trying to transfer data I getting nil

Comment: delegate?.sendData(someData) == nil

Comment: So finally, I did it! But I used == let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddTransactionViewController") as? AddTransactionViewController {
            vc.defaultTransaction.category = currentCell
            navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the selected category to the previous view controller using closure

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {   
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let secondVC = segue.destination as? SecondViewController {
            secondVC.selectedOption = { selectedOption in
                print(selectedOption)
                //change category title here
            }
        }
    }

}
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    var selectedOption: ((String) -> Void)?
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selectedOption?("Selected Option String")
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should pass "Completion handler" when you move to your category selection controller like

```
(String)->(Void)
```

and when you pop it, pass your category in this clouser