# TextFields don't get updated with values in unwind function Swift

Tags: swift, unwind-segue

I have `textfields` that should get a value displayed once returning from a `TableViewController` where user selects a cell. I get that value in `unwind`function, but `textfields`don't get updated. When printing the value it prints correctly on unwinding, so `unwind`should be set correctly, but it just don't get displayed in it's `textfield`. I also tried `prepare(for unwind:`in `TableViewController`but with same results. Can you see what I'm doing wrong?
As always many thanks.

unwind function:

```
@IBAction func unwindToDetailsVc(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        //Insert function to be run upon dismiss of VC2
        print("unwindSegue triggered")
        if let vc = segue.source as? CityTableViewController {
            print("segue source is city vc : \(String(describing: vc.city!))")

            self.cityTextField.text = vc.city
        }
        if let vc = segue.source as? RegionTableViewController {
            print("segue source is region vc : \(String(describing: vc.region!))")
            self.regionTextField.text = vc.region
        }
        if let vc = segue.source as? CountryTableViewController {
            print("segue source is country vc : \(String(describing: vc.country!))")
            self.countryTextField.text = vc.country
        }
    }
```

`didSelect` in `TableView`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CityTableViewCell
        self.city = cell.cityLabel.text ?? ""
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindSegue", sender: self)
//        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

prepare for unwind:

```
override func prepare(for unwind: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if unwind.identifier == "unwindSegue"  {
            if let detailsVc = unwind.destination as? ShopDetailsTableViewController {
                detailsVc.cityTextField.text! = city
            }
        }
    }
```

textfield delegate function:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        print("Editing textfield")
        if textField.accessibilityIdentifier == "city" {
            print("Editing city textfield")
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "citySegue", sender: self)
        } else if textField.accessibilityIdentifier == "region" {
            print("Editing regio textfield")
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "regionSegue", sender: self)
        } else if textField.accessibilityIdentifier == "country" {
            print("Editing country textfield")
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "countrySegue", sender: self)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Instead of using all this, you can simply use a `closure` to handle this.

Comment: @PGDev thanks. Do you mean a `closure` in `unwind` or where? I didn't understand what you meant, can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: @RajeshKumarR thanks for the link, but I'm not sure how to apply your solution there as I'm performing the `segue`to next view controller from a `UITextField`. I still need to understand why the correct returning value is not applied to the corresponding `UITextField`first, then I might use a more advanced coding.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a **`closure`** to solve this kind of problem statement,

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func openTableVC(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if let controller = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TableViewController") as? TableViewController {
            controller.handler = {[weak self](city) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.textField.text = city
                }
            }
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
        }
    }
}

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var handler: ((String)->())?

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let city = "Delhi"
        self.handler?(city)
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

The above code is generic and will work in every case from where you want to open `TableViewController`.

Comment: I'm trying to use your code. If I'm not mistaking I have to use the instantiation code from your `openTableVC` instead of my `perform(segue` in my `textFieldDidBeginEditing`. But it's not instantiating it. I'm using. a`TabBar`controller for main navigation, so I think that's complicating instantiation a bit as `CityTableView`is not in those tabs. That is why I used `perform(segue`in the first place.

Comment: Can you elaborate the view hierarchy a bit more clearly?

Comment: to explain it a bit better basically I have a `TabBar` navigation control with seven main views, one of which is a profile `DetailsVIewController`. This one has textfields where you put your details in. For city, region and country I made three view controllers with a `TableView` to select a parameter from, so when you go adding your city in `cityTextField` you actually go selecting one from the `CityTableViewController` and once selected, go back to `DetailsViewController` and so on for region and country.

Comment: I actually found my error that caused textfield not to display the value and fixed it, but I really want to implement you solution code as it is way cleaner and shorter that the logic I used which is more basic. Using closures, once you master it, is obviously more convenient. Thank you very much

Comment: Sure. Do upvote and accept the answer so it could help others.

Comment: Well, actually your answer is another way of doing it , shouldn't I just post what my problem was as the solution as others may incur in the same mistake? I mean, of course your code is greatly welcomed, but the code I posted actually works, the problem resided in `viewWillAppear`that contained a refresh that made textfield display nil values

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out what I was doing wrong, I was calling the functions loading  from `CoreData`user details and displaying them in `viewWillAppear`. Once I moved them in `saveButton`after the saving to `CoreData`function call, it all works as expected. Textfield get updated with select values from tableviews.

Many thank to @PGDev for sharing a more convenient way of coding this, without all the `if` `else`statements and `unwinds`. Great example of higher level coding.