# pass data from ViewContoller to popOver ViewController in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, function, uiviewcontroller

I have a main ViewController and a button to view a popover view controller which has two buttons
[image]

the functions for the two buttons are on the main view controller, how can I pass the functions to the popover view?

I have a button which will open the popover view

Comment: Please refer to this link... The solution is here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19343519/pass-data-back-to-previous-viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

Just move the functions in the pop over view controller, and make a protocol for popover view controller, and make mainViewController conform to that protocol to perform functionality there.