# Can be change UILabel value dynamically in protocol?

Tags: swift, uikit

I have a problem when after use UILabel with optional value after show custom dialog by xib. after data passed on protocol. it UILabel can't change value because it first time i was develop in swift.

```
label?.text = data
```

and 'data' get from pass a protocol value.

But in Android Java. if i used

```
label.setText(data)
```

value will be change in label.

maybe, if you can tell me why didn't work it? i was grateful. thank you for help me..

Comment: `data` which kind of data type?

Comment: `data` is kind of `Data` than you need to convert it into string.

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: of course data is data type is String Optionals, sir @jatinfl

Comment: @MichaelFernando please show your code. what are you doing?

Comment: okay. so, label?.text = data implemented on inside of extension. but, it not focus problem. because it's about UILabel can't response update data from protocol

Comment: first of all `protocol` is custom delegate which pass data or instructions one to another view controller. so without code how we can know where you stuck.

Comment: how protocol will work see here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/33229483/15466569

Comment: for the example i use in secondary class NSObjectProtocol such protocol passdata:NSObjectProtocol{func passmaindata(data: String)} and main class i used extension secondaryClass: passdata which i used a called normal pass. @jatinfl

Comment: @MichaelFernando see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it might be a main thread problem for UI updates.
Try and see if this works:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asnyc {
   label?.text = data
}
```

Comment: it didn't work inside protocol, sir. although i used optional value in secondary class in xib

Comment: addition my comment. when i print label?.text, its shown nil value although i used .layoutIfNeeded() or .setNeedsDisplay() @infiniteObj

Comment: @MichaelFernando When it is showing nil, that means your protocol is not receiving the string from the delegate object that called that protocol function. Have you set the "delegate = self" for the delegate method that is calling your protocol? I sometimes make a mistake of missing this out.

Comment: i think in secondary class. i have delegate it self such as labellist.delegate = self. @infiniteObj

Comment: yeah, it's worked. i found this my problem in my secondary class when i init variable in protocol. thank you very much @infiniteObj

Answer (score 0):

suppose you need data back from `ViewController2` to `ViewController1`

**ViewController1.swift**

```
protocol VC2Delegate {
    func getString(newString:String)
}

class ViewController1: UIViewController, VC2Delegate {
    @IBAction func btnJumpOnVC2(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let vc2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController2") as? ViewController2 else {return}
        vc2.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        vc2.dataDelgate = self
        self.present(vc2, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }    
 
    func getString(newString: String) {
        label?.text = newString
    }
}
```

**ViewController2.swift**

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController {
    var dataDelgate : VC2Delegate?

    @IBAction func btnBackToVC1(_ sender: Any) {
        dataDelgate?.getString(newstring:"Perfect")
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }    
}
```

checkout and find what you miss in your code.

Comment: okay, thank you very much @jatinfl. i caan try it your solution

Comment: as same as me. in xib, it didn't work if use storyboard and optional value in secondary class